# Limit argument type to package, possible?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

In `AS3`, the below method accepts a parameter of any type:

```
public function myFunc(data:*) :void
```

Is it possible to limit the type to a specific package? Something like this maybe:

```
public function myFunc(data:(my.package:*)) //Accepts any type from my.package
```

Comment: What should your function do if it'll be fed a String?

Comment: @Vesper: Throw an error, but I was also hoping for compile time checking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, but will only have type control at runtime.

```
import flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName;
public function myFunc(data:*):void {
    if (data is Object) {
        var fqcn:String=getQualifiedClassName(data);
        if (fqcn.slice(0,10)!='my.package') return; // otherwise work
        // work here
    } // simple types process if needed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a design issue.  One way to make this work during compile is if the parameter type is a custom class:

```
public function myFunc(data:MyCustomClass):void
```

Assuming that all the classes within `my.package` are varied, you could create a custom base class that extends `Object` and have all of your classes within `my.package` extend from this base class.  Of course, If, however, the inheritance of your `my.package` classes is less broad you wouldn't need to reach so far.  For example, you should only extend from `DisplayObject` if all the classes within `my.package` are of that type.

There may also be a way to accomplish what you want using `namespaces`, but I'm unsure.